# как сделать прозрачный или белый фон webp в php?

Tags: php, webp

как сделать прозрачный фон или хотябы белый для изображения webp?

```
$gd_info = gd_info();
        
            if($gd_info['WebP Support']) {
                $image_new_webp = 'cache/webp/' . utf8_substr($filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($filename, '.')) . '-' . (int)$width . 'x' . (int)$height . '.webp';
            
                if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $image_new) && (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $image_new_webp) || (filemtime(DIR_IMAGE . $image_new) > filemtime(DIR_IMAGE . $image_new_webp)))) {
                    $path = '';

                    $directories = explode('/', dirname($image_new_webp));

                    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
                        $path = $path . '/' . $directory;

                        if (!is_dir(DIR_IMAGE . $path)) {
                            @mkdir(DIR_IMAGE . $path, 0777);
                        }
                    }
            
                    $extension = strtolower($extension);
                    
                    if ($extension == 'gif') {
                        $img = imagecreatefromgif(DIR_IMAGE.$image_new);
                    } elseif ($extension == 'png') {
                        $img = imagecreatefrompng(DIR_IMAGE.$image_new);
                    } elseif ($extension == 'jpeg' || $extension == 'jpg') {
                        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg(DIR_IMAGE.$image_new);
                    } else {
                        $img = '';
                    }
                    
                    if($img) {
                        imagepalettetotruecolor($img);
                        imagewebp($img, DIR_IMAGE.$image_new_webp);
                        imagedestroy($img);
                    }
                }
            
                if(is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $image_new_webp)) {
                    if(stripos($this->request->server['REQUEST_URI'], 'admin') === false && isset($this->request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT']) && strpos($this->request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'image/webp') !== false) {
                        $image_new = $image_new_webp;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: А в чём трудность? [Второй коммент](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagewebp.php#124925) на php.net рассказывает как конвертировать png в webp. С gif аналогично. А у jpeg нет альфаканала (прозрачных пикселей).

Comment: @ЕгорБанин конвертировать то получается, просто если прозрачный фон то картинка выходит с черным фоном, а нужен белый либо прозрачный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда сталкиваетесь с такими проблемами, то отбросьте лишний код, оставьте самое необходимое и экспериментируйте. Возможно вы неправильно понимаете проблему или упустили какую-то важную деталь. Вот, например, PNG с прозрачным фоном конвертируется в WEBP с прозрачным фоном.

```php
<?php

$png = base64_decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeCAYAAAA7MK6iAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAHtJREFUSIntk1EOgCAMQ9F4/yvjF0SbbVBFjdqX8MNWCmRNSQhxEXngOWWZTKTxtj8beqzheV5/aIwvaPWG+jkQI+5tj+gZ46HImIWJ3653IYU4YBgZjBtS65ax9wpvqst+d2Y947Ox6eK1w/Uv41tmgaWZ78e+WojvsQJkcBcaPFiZPwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
$img = imagecreatefromstring($png);
imagepalettetotruecolor($img);
imagealphablending($img, true);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
header('Content-Type: image/webp');
imagewebp($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Заведите у себя на компьютере папку с экспериментами. Как только сталкиваетесь с непонятным поведением программы, создавайте там папку типа gd2_png_to_webp и накидывайте код для проверки. Когда стало ясно как всё работает, возвращаетесь к рабочему проекту.